# Is it bad practice to place a LiPoly battery underneath a PCB in an electronic device?

Tags: batteries, pcb

I'm designing an electronic device and have considered placing the plcb on top of the battery within the device to minimize space used. My gut tells me this is unwise however. What concerns are there for placing a pcb on top of/underneath a lipoly battery?

Comment: This is done in millions of mobile phones (and they don't *all* catch fire), so there shouldn't be any issue ...

Comment: Does your PCB get hot? Li-Ion batteries can go into thermal runaway if they overheat. Are there through-hole components on your PCB? This could create a concern for puncture.

Comment: There will be some through hole components, however it is possible for me to move them away from the area of the battery

Answer (score 1):

This is standard practice, but, as with anything, you have to consider your specific design.

Here are some possible problems:

- If you have anything sharp underneath your PCB, such as through-hole component leads, these can puncture the battery.
- The battery may interfere with any RF (or other high-speed) features on your board. Similar to putting the PCB against a metal enclosure.
- Similarly, it will certainly interfere with the radiation patterns of any antennas on your PCB which are occluded by the battery.
- If the PCB has heat-sensitive components a charging battery may effect them.
- Conversely, if the PCB will get hot on its own, this could cause issues with the battery. Many battery chargers use temperature feedback. Also, a battery can fail if it gets too hot.